# SSH config file works globally but not as command line parameter

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, openssh

I have written a ssh config file that specifies a typical jump server setting:

```
Host host1
  HostName 11.11.11.11
  User useroo
  IdentityFile some/key/file


Host host2
  HostName 192.11.11.10
  User useroo
  IdentityFile some/other/key
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p host1
```

I can successfully connect with `ssh host2` when I save this as `~/.ssh/config`. However if I save the config somewhere else as `xy_conf`, calling `ssh -F xy_conf host2` results in an error saying

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname host1: Name or service not known
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Is this the expected behavior? How else can I set this config temporarily? I don't want to set it as `~/.ssh/config`.

OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different location for `ssh_config` affects only the first call of `ssh`, but not the second (from `ProxyCommand). You need to pass the same argument to the second`ssh` too:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -F xy_conf -W %h:%p host1
```